# Missing something important with ClientRpc (Unity Mirror)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet, unity3d-mirror

I'm having an issue with ClientRpc never being called any client objects. I've trolled the internet for hours, but I can't find any clues as to why my implementation isn't working.
I'm following an order of events like so:

1. Add players in a lobby
2. Switch scene to the gameplay scene
3. Generate random tiles on the server
4. Send tile data to the clients using Rpc for rendering

However, the rendering function never gets called.

NetworkManager.cs

```
public override void OnServerReady(NetworkConnection conn)
{
    base.OnServerReady(conn);
    //Make sure they're all ready
    for (int i = RoomPlayers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!RoomPlayers[i].IsReady)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    //Previously add SpawnTiles to OnServerReadied
    OnServerReadied?.Invoke(conn);
}
```

GameManager.cs

```
private void SpawnTiles(NetworkConnection conn)
{
    //Generate rawTiles beforehand
    Debug.Log(conn.isReady);
    Debug.Log("Entered spawn tiles");
    RpcSpawnTiles(rawTiles);
}

[ClientRpc]
public void RpcSpawnTiles(short[] rawTiles)
{
    Debug.Log("Client spawning tiles");
}
```

And this is my output when run on a host:

```
True
Entered spawn tiles
```

It appears to never enter the Rpc function :(
Is there something super obvious that I'm missing? My GameManager does have a NetworkID attached to it

Comment: any errors in the console?? If the `short[] rawTiles` is too big, an error might be thrown due sending a too big amount of data at once

Comment: on the other hand does the GameManager.cs inherit from `NetworkBehaviour` ? if not the network behaviour wont take place

Comment: `My GameManager does have a NetworkID attached to it` .. you can only send Network stuff through a component that `A` is a `NetworkBehaviour` and `B` this automatically also requries the GameObject that component is attached to to have a `NetworkIdendity`

Comment: The console doesn't output any error messages. There's the possibility that it's too big- `short[] rawTiles` is a flattened 100x100 array. GameManager inherits from NetworkBehaviour. My assumption right now is that the scene change is causing the problem, and that the `GameManager` has not spawned yet on the client when the Rpc is called.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be a combination of things that I had to do to get it to work- I'm not entirely sure which one worked, but if you are having these problems, these are some of the things I had to check-

1. Just basic code. Make sure that the appropriate things are being created on the client, host, or server
2. Make sure that there aren't any race conditions, especially when working with changing scenes. You can call stuff from `OnClientSceneChanged` and `OnServerSceneChanged`
3. As derHugo pointed out, I was not checking to see if my package could even be sent. It turns out that the maximum size that can be sent is 1200 bytes, while I was trying to send 100x100x4 bytes. This error didn't occur when I was testing on the host, only when there was an external client